# Is there an hourly API/DML limit? Or per-user limit?

Tags: api, dml, tooling-api

I know there's the daily/monthly limits, which we aren't exceeding. However, we are seeing an issue where one of our Integration Users is seeing their API calls stalling out, but at the top of the hour the calls resume.

Is there a resource that highlights the per user or per hour limits? Or is there anything available via the tooling API perhaps?

Comment: There are per hour scheduled flow limits IIRC.

Comment: The downvotes without comments are unwarranted. I'm experiencing a rate limit that's not documented without using any hourly limited objects. If you're downvoting, at least explain why you're downvoting. I don't post a question unless I've researched it exhaustively.

Comment: Disclosure: I did not downvote. However, there is no indication in the question to suggest research having been undertaken, with no citations or explanation of investigation. Your comment helps since you mention not using known hourly rated objects (though again listing what you know to be hourly would help cement your position of having researched).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that we were not caching our session token and thus exceeding the hourly login limit per user. This did not have to do with the API limit per hour.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312767&type=1